# what do i have to do to use NX on a different port than 22 (SSH)

Tags: configuration, ssh, nx

I have installed OpenSSH server on my Ubuntu Linux box (10.04). I can SSH to the box properly, no problem. I have to use port 443/TCP. No problem accessing a shell prompt with PuTTY or other SSH client. Hoewver, when I try to use NX to have a graphical session, it is not responding. I thought that NX is simply using the settings used by /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Are there other parameters for NX that I should change so that it listens on port 443 ?

I use NX from nomachine.com, and the version of all components is: 3.4.0-5

Thanks :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I installed and tested the ssh server before doing anything with NX. So I know that my router is properly configured.

Comment: You can also edit you question of you have some addenda

Comment: The configuration is to be done on the server, not the client. The server responds fine when I connect from outside, but not from inside.

Comment: And I checked the routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the commercial NX, edit /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg, change *SSHDPort*, and restart NX.

(A little more... I like to link the NX etc directory.)

```
ln -s /usr/NX/etc /etc/nx
sudo vim /etc/nx/server.cfg
```

Change SSHDPort and save.

```
/etc/init.d/nxserver restart
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FreeNX, you will need to edit `/etc/nxserver/node.conf`. In the General FreeNX Directives, locate this lines:

```
# The port number where local 'sshd' is listening.
#SSHD_PORT=22
```

Uncomment the second one and put there the port where sshd is listening. Note that I haven't been able to test it, so please comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, I use the Commercial NX. But I give a point for the fact that this can be useful for all FreeNX users out there.....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there should be some sort of GUI configurator available in the programs menu.

It also looks like there's a wizard you can run on the command line with

```
nxclient --wizard
```

More info [here](http://www.nomachine.com/documents/configuration/pdf/client-guide.pdf).

Comment: You might also find the Ubuntu Community Doc on NomachineNX useful, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX